# Fetch element that fires ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting to know AngularJS and I am having trouble building the scripts destined to handle all the angular's logic while mixing jQuery's effects and such.

So I am doing a simple CRUD "to-dos" app and when I'm deleting a task I'd like to make the task div to fade a way in some fancy way.

So this is where the `deleteTask` method is called:

```
<div class="delete-task glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deleteTask(task)"></div>
```

And here the definition the angular controller:

```
$scope.deleteTask = function(task) {
    var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
    $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
};
```

In this last piece of code, how can I retrieve the div that called the method? I want to know that DOM element so I can apply some effect to the parent div and make it fade away in some pretty manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question first, and then explain better approach.

You can get DOM element object initiated event using `$event` object:

```
<div class="delete-task glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deleteTask(task, $event)"></div>
```

and in controller you can read `$event.target` object, which is the DOM element you are after:

```
$scope.deleteTask = function(task, e) {
    // DOM element is e.target
    var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
    $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
};
```

However, you **should not** do this. Mixing jQuery code with jQuery in controller like this is not very good approach. You have at least two better options:

1). Use [`ngAnimate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module for any fancy animation effect you like. In this case I  would use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive and define necessary CSS rules to transition/animate element.

2). Build custom directive in which you would use any type of DOM manipulations.

Comment: yeah I mentioned that it seemed weird to me mixing angular logic with jQuery effects, changing classes, etc... could you give me some sources where I can see how this situations are dealt?

Comment: Check ngIf link in my question, it has an example of usage with animation.

Comment: actually I can't think of a way of using `ng-if` in this case, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` has access to the `$event` param:

```
ng-click="deleteTask(task, $event)"

$scope.deleteTask = function(task, e) {
    var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
    $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);

    console.log(e.target); //caller
};
```

As the other answer says, you *shouldn't* do this... instead, apply a CSS class to transition the element out (one way) (checkout `ngAnimate` for nice enter/exit animations on repeaters)